# MeteorJS / Mongo Data Structures - Which option is best for the long-term?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

My team and I have run into a dilemma and wanted to get a consensus on the community here as to what would be the better option to go with.

We are trying to build a Meteor JS route like:

> **domain.com/main-slug/all/child-slug**

The options are we either:

> 1) publish the main-slug with every child-slug record or
>
> 2) we attach the a new field to every record corresponding to that child-slug as a foreign key.

The con with publishing the main-slug with every child-slug record (**option 1**) would mean we would have to sub to more data and the child-slug records on this publish are already extensive (1+ million records).

The con with attaching a new field to every record corresponding to that child-slug as a foreign key (**option 2**) would mean we would have to rework the data and have a tougher DB migration.

In terms of optimal performance, which option would have the most pros rather than cons?

Comment: better off asking this question on the meteor forums or mongo forums

Comment: i did log it in those other forums. figured i'd put it here considering the size of the community. i apologize